# About Algebraic Statistics

Tags: statistics, algebraic-geometry

Recently, I find that the website of professor Bernd Sturmfels in Berkeley mentions Algebraic Statistics.

I am quite interested in both Algebra and Statistics. But I have never know the cross field between them.

Can anyone introduce some reccent work about **Algebraic Statistics**?

Comment: There's a book about it by Lior Pachter and Berndt Stufmfels.

Comment: This is in fact the second Elk theory that was not presented after the first one.